# In scala eclipse how do I use a library in my workspace

Tags: eclipse, scala, jar, build

This should be super easy.  I'm using Scala IDE 3.0.4 of Eclipse.

I have
Workspace
  Common/src/Common/*.scala
  MyProject/src/(default package)/foo.scala

How do I get MyProject to use my Common library code?

In MyProject foo.scala I import Common.Common (my package object)
In MyProject properties, I've added a Project Reference.
I've also tried 12 ways of adding it to the java build path.

What did I miss?

Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

You don't indicate what the 12 ways you've tried are, but I think the following should work, assuming `Common` is another project in your workspace:

- Make sure the `Common` project and `MyProject` project are both open.
- Right click on `MyProject`->`Build Path`->`Configure Build Path`.  That should open a dialog.
- Choose the `Projects` tab
- Click on the `Add` button - it should bring up another dialog where you can check the `Common` project.  Thereafter it should appear in the list under the `Projects` tab.

Later, whenever you open the `MyProject` project the `Common` project will automatically be opened as well.

Comment: Thanks, I also had my import statement wrong.  It should have been import Common.Common._ so that I could use my higher order functions.  I would up vote if I could :-)